# how to configure git repository with 2 server(test-main) without local

Tags: php, git

I made web service by PHP alone.

now, my boss hire two developer. So, I have to setting DevOps for co-worker.

But, I know only one style (server pull local, local push server) DevOps.

I want to configure between test-server and main-server(main-server pull test-server, test-server push main-server).

Let me know how to configuration this type DevOps.

I just try install git repository in main-server. But test-server do not pull any data as test yet.